# Vscode formatting "On Save" different for two projects

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I have added two project on my workspace. In first project I have Eslint with prettier, and I have global setting formating html, css, js to prettier. In second project I have only Eslint, but when I click `Ctrl + S` Vscode formating my code to prettier setting and Eslint return errors. How I can resolve it ?

I try add settings.json to my second project:

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true
}
```

but it's not work.